# Convert TimeString yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss to NSDate Time HH:mm AM/PM in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nstimezone

I want to convert **Time string** to **NSDate Time** into **HH:mm: a** format. I have a code right now

```
let defaultStartTime = json!["start_schedule_datetime"] as? String
 let defaultEndTime = json!["end_schedule_datetime"] as? String



                    print(defaultStartTime,defaultEndTime)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        let dtf = NSDateFormatter()
                        dtf.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
                        dtf.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"

                        let defaultStartdate : NSDate = dtf.dateFromString(defaultStartTime!)!
                        let defaultEnddate : NSDate = dtf.dateFromString(defaultEndTime!)!

                        print(defaultStartdate,defaultEnddate)

                        self.startTime.date = defaultStartdate
                        self.endTime.date = defaultEnddate
                        self.endTime.reloadInputViews()
                        self.startTime.reloadInputViews()

                        })
```

**Where:-**

```
start_schedule_datetime = 2016-05-27 13:35:00
end_schedule_datetime = 2016-05-27 19:35:00
```

Here i want time into **HH:mm a**. But when i am trying to do that i am getting

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Can any one please help me here. Thank you

Comment: You'r date format should be similar to start_schedule_datetime. If you just want to store the date time then store it's converted. Later you can convert it to HH:mm a format for display

Comment: @Bhavin Yes i am sure my default defaultStartTime or defaultEndTime is not null

Comment: @Ankita Shah you are right i did convert it but do you have any idea how convert string to NSDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here one of the best solution for everyone.
You can easily get what you want from the date. And also you can learn about dateformatter.

**Reference 1:**  http://nsdateformatter.com/

**EDIT 1**

**Reference 2:** [For Ready made code](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/03/nsdateformatter-in-swift.html)

Good luck.

Comment: Answer Checked Thank you Very much @Chetan Prajapati it's very help full for me

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Answer. Both Current date and Date picker date is displaying.

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())) //if you want current date
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(yourdatepickername.date) //if you want your selective date
```

Comment: Answer Checked i try to update with your solution and it's got working 
Thank you very much for your help